# How can I use ~/.XCompose with IBus and KDE plasma (on NixOS)

Tags: xorg, nixos, plasma5, ibus, compose-key

I want to use IBus with libpinyin on my NixOS install with KDE plasma.
IBus is installed and works fine, with the following config in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`

```
# use IBus for input
i18n.inputMethod = {
    enabled = "ibus";
    ibus.engines = with pkgs.ibus-engines; [libpinyin];
};
```

I also want to be able to compose some specific characters when I am using libpinyin in 'English' mode or when I am using the English input engine.
Following various guides I tried the following configuration:

`~/.xsessionrc`:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym ISO_Level3_Shift = Multi_key"
```

`~/.XCompose`:

```
include "%L"
# Compose keys for pinyin with tone marks
<Multi_key> <a> <a> : "ā" 
<Multi_key> <a> <e> : "ē" 
<Multi_key> <a> <i> : "ī" 
<Multi_key> <a> <o> : "ō" 
<Multi_key> <a> <u> : "ū" 
<Multi_key> <s> <a> : "á" 
<Multi_key> <s> <e> : "é" 
<Multi_key> <s> <i> : "í" 
<Multi_key> <s> <o> : "ó" 
<Multi_key> <s> <u> : "ú" 
<Multi_key> <d> <a> : "ǎ" 
<Multi_key> <d> <e> : "ě" 
<Multi_key> <d> <i> : "ǐ" 
<Multi_key> <d> <o> : "ǒ" 
<Multi_key> <d> <u> : "ǔ" 
<Multi_key> <f> <a> : "à" 
<Multi_key> <f> <e> : "è" 
<Multi_key> <f> <i> : "ì" 
<Multi_key> <f> <o> : "ò" 
<Multi_key> <f> <u> : "ù"
```

With this configuration, no compose characters work. If I run `bash ~/.xsessionrc` then I can see that `xev` reports the correct compose characters like so;

If I type `<alt_gr> <s> <a>`, then various events appear in the log, one of which includes this line:

```
XmbLookupString gives 3 bytes: (61 cc 81) "á"
```

So the xsessionrc file isn't running at the right time (on login I suppose), but furthermore, no other applications actually allow me to use the compose combinations. Both `kwrite` and `chromium` ignore the XCompose config, even after using the suggested config below in my `~/.profile`;

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

(This config is getting set, as `env` shows these variables as being set.)

To be clear it is only xev that shows that the config *might* be somewhat correct. No real application that actually needs input will let me compose these characters.
How can I get the compose behaviour I want?